# pyspark RDDs strip attributes of numpy subclasses

Tags: numpy, pyspark, rdd, numpy-ndarray

I've been fighting an unexpected behavior when attempting to construct a subclass of numpy ndarray within a map call to a pyspark RDD.  Specifically, the attribute that I added within the ndarray subclass appears to be stripped from the resulting RDD.

The following snippets contain the essence of the issue.

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls,shape,extra=None,*args):
        obj = super().__new__(cls,shape,*args)
        obj.extra = extra
        return obj
    def __array_finalize__(self,obj):
        if obj is None:
            return
        self.extra = getattr(obj,"extra",None)

def shape_to_array(shape):
    rval = MyArray(shape,extra=shape)
    rval[:] = np.arange(np.product(shape)).reshape(shape)
    return rval
```

If I invoke shape_to_array directly (not under pyspark), it behaves as expected:

```
x = shape_to_array((2,3,5))
print(x.extra)
```

outputs:

```
(2, 3, 5)
```

But, if I invoke shape_to_array via a map to an RDD of inputs, it goes wonky:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("Steps").getOrCreate().sparkContext

rdd = sc.parallelize([(2,3,5),(2,4),(2,5)])
result = rdd.map(shape_to_array).cache()
print(result.map(lambda t:type(t)).collect())
print(result.map(lambda t:t.shape).collect())
print(result.map(lambda t:t.extra).collect())
```

Outputs:

```
[<class '__main__.MyArray'>, <class '__main__.MyArray'>, <class '__main__.MyArray'>]

[(2, 3, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5)]

22/10/15 15:48:02 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 23)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 686, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 678, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 273, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 81, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/folders/w7/42_p7mcd1y91_tjd0jzr8zbh0000gp/T/ipykernel_94831/2519313465.py", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'MyArray' object has no attribute 'extra'
```

What happened to the *extra* attribute of the MyArray instances?

Thanks much for any/all suggestions

**EDIT:  A bit of additional info.**  If I add logging inside the shape_to_array function just before the return, I can verify that the *extra* attribute **does** exist on the DataArray object that is being returned.  But when I attempt to access the DataArray elements in the RDD from the main driver, they're gone.

Comment: Does pyspark say anything about using `ndarray` subclasses?

Comment: @hpaulj.  I tried looking through both the pyspark and the numpy documentation for a clue to what the issue might be.  Global searches came up empty when searching for any cross references---searching for ndarray in the pyspark documentation yielded no hits and searching for spark in the numpy documentation yielded no hits.

Comment: Need to clarify that searching pyspark for ndarray yielded no useful hits.  There were hits, but none that addressed any sort of compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a night of sleeping on this, I remembered that I have often had issues with pyspark RDDs where the error message had to do the return type not working with pickle.

I wasn't getting that error message this time because numpy.ndarray does work with pickle.  **BUT...** the `__reduce__` and `__setstate__` methods of numpy.ndarray known nothing of the added *extra* attribute on the MyArray subclass. This is where *extra* was being stripped.

Adding the following two methods to MyArray solved everything.

```
def __reduce__(self):
    mthd,cls,args = super().__reduce__(self)
    return mthd, cls, args + (self.extra,)

def __setstate__(self,args):
    super().__setstate__(args[:-1])
    self.extra = args[-1]
```

Thank you to anyone who took some time to think about my question.